# regex to remove everything after the last comma in a string

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to write a regex in Perl which will remove everything after the last comma in a string. I know the substring after the last comma is a number or some other substring, so no commas there.

Example: `some\string,/doesnt-really.metter,5`.

I would like the regex to remove the last comma and the `5` so the output would be: `some\string,/doesnt-really.metter`

I am not allowed to use any additional module only with regex. So which regex should I use?

Another example:

`string_with,,,,,_no_point,some_string => string_with,,,,,_no_point`

Comment: Match `/,[^,]*$/` and replace by empty string.

Comment: Yet another way: `/.*\K,.*//` -- match all (`.*`) greedily, so up to the _last_ occurrence of the following character (comma here) and drop all those matches (`\K`), match a comma and then all else (`.*`) and remove it.

Answer (score 7):

If the comma is always followed by one or more digits, you can use: `s/,\d+$//`. More generally, use `s/,[^,]*$//` (match a comma followed by zero or more non-comma characters followed by end-of-string).

Answer (score 0):

This Regex captures everything before the last `,`.

```
(.*),[^,]*$
```

Answer (score -1):

```
perl -n -e 'chomp; s/(.+,)/$1/g; print "$_\n";' inputfile.txt
```

Just run this command directly on terminal, the regex just selects all text which comes before last comma).

Comment: I don't know even after typing correctly, why chomp($_) not showing underscore above.

Comment: Please test your code. Replacing a matched pattern by itself isn't very useful.

Comment: You don't need to specify `$_` in either the `chomp` or the substitution.